# What can a firewall do for a up-to-date system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall

I am using Windows 10 OS and update in time. That means it is almost impossible to find a vulnerability in my system. So if I get a firewall, can it do any good for me?

Comment: Your assumption "*it is almost impossible to find a vulnerability*" is wrong. Every running computer system is vulnerable.

Comment: The built-in Windows Firewall does half the job, and the firewall within your security suite takes care of the rest.So can u explain your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one reason why you need a firewall is to protect your computer from Unauthorized Remote Access, updating windows doesn't mean you are safe! it only means that you have the latest fixes and patches to known vulnerabilities.

.a firewall can for example only allow your applications's or game's traffic on a certain port and block other unwanted traffic that could be an unauthorized access that could exploit an unknown/new vulnerability.

.a firewall can block traffic that is not initiated from you computer.

.a firewall can help with avoiding DDOS attacks.

.a firewall can block known malwares (if for some reason installed them self on your computer) from initiating communication with its own servers.

there are several open ports on any operating system that are critical to be able to use anything related to network and internet, simply updating the OS wont deny unwanted access on these ports if vulnerabilities are discovered.

keep in mind, not all vulnerabilities are known to the public or to the OS updater, and some if known could take time to be deployed.